# Eloquent hasOne Relationship Returns NULL even when related records exist

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a small practice accounting app that I'm building using Laravel to provide a REST api.  I am trying to use eloquent relationships to handle delivering objects including their relations.

Right now I have a "Transaction" model which looks like the following.

```
class Transaction extends Model
{
  protected $table = "transaction";

  protected $fillable = [
    "transaction_type_id",
    "account_id",
    "description",
    "amount",
    "comments",
    "transaction_status_id",
    "posting_date"
  ];

  protected $guarded = [
    "id"
  ];

  public static function create(array $attributes = Array()) {

    $account = BankAccount::find($attributes["account_id"]);

    if ($attributes["transaction_type_id"] == 1) {
        //Credit
        $account["balance"] += $attributes["amount"];
    } else if ($attributes["transaction_type_id"] == 2) {
        //Debit
        $account["balance"] -= $attributes["amount"];
    }

    $account->save();
    parent::create($attributes);    
  }

  public function transactionType() {
    return $this->hasOne("App\Model\TransactionType", "id");
  }

  public function transactionStatus() {
    return $this->hasOne("App\Model\TransactionStatus", "id");
  }
}
```

The TransactionStatus model looks like this

```
class TransactionStatus extends Model
{
  protected $table = "transaction_status";

  protected $guarded = [
      "id", "description"
  ];
}
```

And the TransactionType model looks like this

```
class TransactionType extends Model
{
  protected $table = "transaction_type";

  protected $guarded = [
    "id", "description"
  ];
}
```

I have the following in my controller

```
return Transaction::with("TransactionType", "TransactionStatus")
    ->where("account_id", $accountId)
    ->get()
    ->toJson();
```

This query returns a result that looks like the following, where the first result returns the relation, but every subsequent record has null.

```
  {
   "id": 1,
   "transaction_type_id": 1,
   "account_id": 1,
   "description": "Morbi metus. Vivamus euismod urna.",
   "amount": "4179.00",
   "comments": "ullamcorper, nisl arcu iaculis enim,",
   "transaction_status_id": 1,
   "posting_date": "2016-12-10 21:24:25",
   "created_at": "2016-12-10 00:00:00",
   "updated_at": "2016-12-10 00:00:00",
   "transaction_type": {
     "id": 1,
     "description": "Credit",
     "created_at": "2016-12-09 13:37:00",
     "updated_at": "2016-12-09 13:37:00"
  },
  "transaction_status": {
    "id": 1,
    "description": "Pending",
    "created_at": "2016-12-09 13:37:00",
    "updated_at": "2016-12-09 13:37:00"
  }
 },
 {
  "id": 3,
  "transaction_type_id": 1,
  "account_id": 1,
  "description": "lorem ut aliquam iaculis, lacus",
  "amount": "2710.00",
  "comments": "ac, eleifend vitae, erat. Vivamus",
  "transaction_status_id": 1,
  "posting_date": "2016-07-16 04:23:34",
  "created_at": "2016-12-10 00:00:00",
  "updated_at": "2016-12-10 00:00:00",
  "transaction_type": null,
  "transaction_status": null
 }
```

The above result makes no sense to me because all of the records in the transaction table have both a transaction_type_id and a transaction_status_id, so these shouldn't be null at all.

I've looked high and low trying to understand why this might happen, but I've not been able to find an explanation.  I've included a screenshot below that indicates how the records look in the table in MySQL as well.

[image]

Comment: Just a side note - in your Transaction model you are using $fillable as well as $guarded, you either $fillable or $guarded should not use both.

Comment: @Donkarnash, Good catch, the docs specified that and I had neglected to remove the $guarded declaration.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution to the problem and it was along the same lines of what IzzEps pointed out.

The way that I had the relationships originally set up is like this.

```
public function transactionType() {
  return $this->hasOne("App\Model\TransactionType", "id");
}

public function transactionStatus() {
  return $this->hasOne("App\Model\TransactionStatus", "id");
}
```

I took another look at the [eloquent relationship docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one) and found this:

> Additionally, Eloquent assumes that the foreign key should have a value matching the id (or the custom $primaryKey) column of the parent. In other words, Eloquent will look for the value of the user's id column in the user_id column of the Phone record. If you would like the relationship to use a value other than id, you may pass a third argument to the hasOne method specifying your custom key: `return $this->hasOne('App\Phone', 'foreign_key', 'local_key');`

When I changed the relationships to this:

```
public function transactionType() {
    return $this->hasOne("App\Model\TransactionType", "id", "transaction_type_id");
}

public function transactionStatus() {
    return $this->hasOne("App\Model\TransactionStatus", "id", "transaction_status_id");
}
```

I got the results I was expecting.  In this case "id" is the foreign key which exists on the transaction_status or transaction_type table, and "transaction_type_id" or "transaction_status_id" is the key that is "local" to the "transaction" table or the "local_key" in the parlance of the docs.

I was not fully specifying how the relationships are defined and what keys the relationships should be using.  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction which, as should be second-nature, was back to the documentation.

So, as always, I should more closely RTM.

Comment: You are getting the results for the relationships from the Transaction model because you are providing the foreign_key and local_key. How would you define the inverse relations i.e. how would you define the relation from TransactionStatus and TransactionType models? Logically a particular TransactionType (debit or credit) will have many Transaction(s) and same way TransactionStatus (maybe pending or approved) will have many Transaction(s) so the relations should be defined as Many-To-One from Transaction model.

Comment: I just saw your answer a few moments ago and it makes a lot of sense.  I'm going to try that and see if it works.

Comment: Were you able to accomplish what you were aiming to?

Comment: Thanks. I managed to get it like this.

public function dispute() {
        return $this->hasOne('App\PaypalDispute', 'transaction_id', 'transaction_id');
}

Answer (score 0):

When defining the following relationships

```
public function transactionType() {
    return $this->hasOne("App\Model\TransactionType", "id");
}

public function transactionStatus() {
   return $this->hasOne("App\Model\TransactionStatus", "id");
}
```

you are specifying the `id` of the `Transaction` model table as the foreign key for both of these relationships (as opposed to the correct correct foreign key's of `transaction_type_id` and `transaction_status_id` respectively). The result is that when calling `Transaction::with("TransactionType", "TransactionStatus")` you are joining both the `transaction_type` and `transaction_status` table on the wrong foreign key (`transaction.id`).

To Fix:

Simply update your relationships to use the correct foreign keys as follows:

```
public function transactionType() {
    return $this->hasOne("App\Model\TransactionType", "transaction_type_id");
}

public function transactionStatus() {
   return $this->hasOne("App\Model\TransactionStatus", "transaction_status_id");
}
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: Or you can leave out the foreignkey from relation definition as table name and foreign key naming are following the same convention.

Comment: This method seemed to me to be the correct way to do this initially as well, the problem is that I got internal server errors when specifying foreign keys like "transaction_type_id" and "transaction_status_id".  See the following:

"QueryException: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'transaction_type.transaction_type_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `transaction_type` where `transaction_type`.`transaction_type_id` in (1, 3, 6, 7...,etc."

Answer (score 0):

Didn't see it the first time. Actually you are storing the `transaction_type_id` and `transaction_status_id` on your `Transaction model. Which essentially means that the relation should be defined as

```
  Transaction belongsTo TransactionType  &  (Inverse) TransactionType hasMany Transaction
```

and

```
  Transaction belongsTo TransactionStatus  & (Inverse) TransactionStatus hasMany Transaction
```

The signatures of `hasOne`, `belongsTo` and `hasMany` are very different.

So the relationships should be defined (as per your current code)

```
class Transaction extends Model
{
    protected $table = "transaction";

      protected $fillable = [
        "transaction_type_id",
        "account_id",
        "description",
        "amount",
        "comments",
        "transaction_status_id",
        "posting_date"
      ];

    public function transactionType()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Model\TransactionType');
    }

    public function transactionStatus()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Model\TransactionStatus');
    }
}  

class TransactionType extends Model
{

    protected $table = "transaction_types";

    protected $fillable = [ /* mass assignable fields */];

    public function transactions()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Model\Transaction');
    }
}


class TransactionStatus
{

    protected $table = "transaction_statuses";

    protected $fillable = [ /* mass assignable fields */];

    public function transactions()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Model\Transaction');
    }
}
```

As per Laravel documentation **Eloquent determines the foreign key of the relationship based on the model name.**

Since you are following desired convention of naming the foreign key corresponding to the Model names

```
transaction_type_id <=> TransactionType and transaction_status_id <=> TransactionStatus
```

you can omit specifying the foreign key as second argument to the relationship function.

After defining the relationships as above

```
return Transaction::with('transactionType', 'transactionStatus')
->where("account_id", $accountId)
->get()
->toJson();
```

should return the desired output for you. Haven't tested but should definitely work.

Hope this helps. Let me know if otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

```
public function dispute() {
    return $this->hasOne('App\PaypalDispute', 'transaction_id', 'transaction_id');
}
```

I managed to get it like this. We should use the local_key as the column name in order to work.